# Setting a (corrected) state value on an input (blur event) does not update the input value when the corrected value is the same

Tags: reactjs, user-input, blur

When a blur event occurs it should rounds out the number entered to the closest factor of 15 within 60 (minutes).

This works:

- When you enter 12 the input value updates to 15
- When you enter 24 the input value updates to 30

This does not work:

- When you enter 12 the input value updates to 15
- When you enter 11 the input value stays 11

My expectation is the input value always falls back to the corrected number even if it is the same while maintaining the functionality of the buttons 0 to 45 below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const InputComponent = ({ defaultValue }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();
  const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState();

  const roundMinutesTo15 = () => {
    const rounded = (Math.round(value / 15) * 15) % 60;
    setNewValue(rounded);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        min="0"
        max="0"
        maxLength="2"
        type="text"
        //
        key={newValue ? newValue : defaultValue}
        defaultValue={newValue ? newValue : defaultValue}
        //
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
        onBlur={() => roundMinutesTo15()}
      />
      <br />
      {/* this works */}
      New Value: {newValue}
<br />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setNewValue(0)}>0</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setNewValue(15)}>15</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setNewValue(30)}>30</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setNewValue(45)}>45</button>

    </>
  );
};

InputComponent.defaultProps = {
  defaultValue: 0
};

export default InputComponent;
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-minsky-6dm8fc?file=/src/InputComponent.jsx:0-810)

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the key and change the `defaultValue` to just `value` and try?

Comment: I tried this yeah, but then I can't type.

Answer (score 0):

If one is interested you can solve this by using a useRef on the input and setting the ref.current.value manually:

```
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement|null>(null);
...
inputRef.current.value = correctedValue;
```